# Amazon ECS: Java SDK equivalent of CLI "aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am rewriting a CLI based deployment process in Java, the CLI version uses a template for a task definition which (after interpolating variables) it registers by passing to

```
aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file
```

I can't see any way to do the same thing from the Java SDK; for policies I was able to make this work by calling

```
String policyDocument = processTemplate();

new CreatePolicyRequest().withPolicyDocument(policyDocument)...
```

Is there any way to do a similar thing with `RegisterTaskDefinitionRequest` ?

It seems likely that under the covers the Java API is constructing this document from the input parameters, is there a way to call a lower level API directly?

Comment: Probably, you can parse the JSON file to `RegisterTaskDefinitionRequest` type using `Jackson ObjectMapper` and send the object to `registerTaskDefinition` method. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Well yes I could, but that's not what I asked. Thanks anyway.